How to submit ADS on the NEW patent center USPTO
anyone has experience to successfully submit your amendment files on the patentcenter
I DID submit it when EFS-WEB was available, now they have only patentcenter, I has a screen shot and I think this is the correct path, but no response was I clicked it.


It may have just not been working when you tried. When you select that option, you should be directed to a new screen to enter the application number and confirmation number.
